# Does the order of CSS styles matter?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm new in this area and I wrote a div style which didn't work properly for firefox 4, opera 11.1 and for ie 8.0 but worked for chrome 11. The code which was a style for a div was the following only with a different order

```
#info_text
{
    background:#fdf6cc;
    width: 650px;
    margin-left:1px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 263;
    min-height: 90px;
}
```

After changing it this way it worked for all the browsers except for the Internet Explorer 8.0.

Can I do something to make it work or it's the problem of the browser?
Does it metter the order in this case?

Comment: when you say it isn't working, what do you mean? Is there a specific property that isn't working, or do you mean none of it is working?

Comment: It draws the color of background in different widths. Opera and Firefox was drowing wider, but ie 8, still draws narrower.

Comment: have you tried adding the px like Jim pointed out?

Comment: Yes, but for ie8 it is still narrower... :(

Comment: The problem is that for ie8 padding-right: 263px; pads also the background color except the text which is in the div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The order doesn't matter in this case.

You are missing units for the `padding-right` property.  Running your code through a validator will flag errors like this.

Comment: +1 Well spotted, you need 'px' in your padding-right property

Comment: I have changed but it does not help. Maybe it could be helpful when I did not change the order.

Comment: By the way in what cases the order matters? (Please don't discuss the case when you override a style.)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to world of web development! All browsers interpret CSS differently, particular old versions of IE (try the above in IE6 for some fun!)

To understand exactly what problems you're having we need to see a working web page with the above.

The order of the CSS doesn't particularly matter to be honest, though obviously later CSS overrides earlier CSS and this something which is used commonly in the industry.

Comment: I hope the newest versin of all browser are standardized. I have read that doing layout of a site with CSS provides cross-browser feature the doing it with tables. But it is still not cross-browser fully, is it?

Answer (score 0):

try opening "developer options" under "tools" in ie, if there is a more specific class, it may be overwriting something, or if something is formatted poorly, IE may be excluding it all together. Another option is "firebug lite", firebug is a very useful tool for getting started with css, javascript, and page structure. Without a link to the page that you are having the problem on, it's very hard to determine the cause, I copied your css and tried it myself, but got the expected result in all browsers

Comment: In developer tools of ie8 I see the following, when I turn off the width 650px, then the width of the div becomes from left to the right of the browser boarder, otherwise it is 650px, but the background color does not continue to be present in the are of padding-right 263px;. The color should be present in the area of right padding, and text should be padded. Only in ie8 this style padds also the background color.

Comment: Like I said you need to put a page online we can check out, I've tested your div and css declaration in ie8 with the expected result, not sure why it's not working for you unless there is something else going on